# Subversion reports "Malformed Network Data" when updating repository over Cisco VPN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Cisco VPN (on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit) to connect to my company network.  When I check out svn repositories, I constantly get this error 2 or 3 seconds after downloading some files.

The problem happens on both TortoiseSVN 1.5.9 and SlikSubversion 1.6.17

I noticed that downloading text files like java or xml often causes this problem, but downloading compressed files(jar etc) is fine.

Is my SVN or VPN setting wrong, or is this a network issue?  How can I make SVN log more details?

PS: I am not using any SSL proxy in my SVN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some reasons , for this , I have seen this happening in windows systems , not in linux ,

1. if you are using  a firewall in your windows machine
2. Or your antivirus scan the network data ( like kaspersky )

you need to disable/add exception for firewall and disable network data scan in antivirus  both while updating or checking out svn repo , this will solve the problem .

You may also have version conflict say your svn is latest and client you use is of lower version .