# svn: E210004: Malformed network data

Tags: svn

When I try to checkout project from SVN Repository I'm getting exception as

svn: E210004: Malformed network data

Can anyone please explain the scenario that when it happen, Because it worked fine last time when I tried.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was a result of trying to check out a repo that was last committed with an older version of my subversion client. Try matching your svn client version to that used for the most recent commit to this repo.

Once you've reverted to an older version of svn, pull down the repo, now upgrade to the svn version you want, then push a commit to the repo. You should now be able to update and checkout from this repo with your updated version of svn.

Comment: Holy cow, that's really crappy that you have to revert back to an older version of svn client to get data committed with an older version of svn client. 

I'm trying to recover a repository I last worked on 10 years ago... fortunately I have the subversion source from back when... but getting it to compile is proving a challenge. Got the repo dump into a newer svn server instance... but trying to `git svn clone` causes the server to vomit.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem on the server end.  I recommend asking your repository's administrator to look into the problem.

If you're connecting through a VPN, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373067/subversion-reports-malformed-network-data-when-updating-repository-over-cisco#12373299) might have some helpful information for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating the subversion plugin jars inside .jenkins\plugins\subversion\WEB-INF\lib and it worked for me. Find jars in svn.zip on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-41342

Jenkins version 1.552. Previous svn plugin version 1.54 and updated svn plugin version 1.8